# How to set the argparse subcommand order in the automatic description

Tags: python, argparse

Consider the following piece of code:

```
$ cat a.py 
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='A')
    parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='B')
    parser_c = subparsers.add_parser('c', help='C')

    args = parser.parse_args()
```

And the simple invocation:

```
$ python a.py --help
usage: a.py [-h] {a,c,b} ...

positional arguments:
  {a,c,b}
    a         A
    b         B
    c         C

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Why the positional arguments are listed as `{a,c,b}` instead of `{a,b,c}` and especially how can I fix this? I have 6 subcommands and the help looks really ugly.

This is Python 2.7.7 FWIW.

Comment: It's possible that it's using a `set` (hence the curly braces) to hold the items, so won't guarantee order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the culprit is setuptools and [scoop](https://github.com/soravux/scoop). When installing the latter with its [setup.py](https://github.com/soravux/scoop/blob/master/setup.py) it requests `argparse>=1.1` in `install_require`. That downloads and installs `arparse 1.2.1` (which is crazy in its own, because in PyPI there is `1.2.2` and `1.3`, besides the "system" argparse, which is `1.1`, from python 2.7).

After that `argparse 1.2.1` is installed, the bugous behavior described in my question appears. And removing it, fixes the issue.

I reported [the bug](https://github.com/soravux/scoop/issues/16) to scoop.

Answer (score 1):

Can you display (print), `subparsers.choices`?  It should be an `OrderedDict`.

The `{}` is produced from the `.choices` attribute of `subparsers`.  While that can be anything iterable (list, dictionary, etc), the current `argparse` code makes an `OrderedDict`, which should display the keys in the order in which they were added.

I'm not aware of a change in this behavior, at least not with in the past couple of years.  But I could dig into its history.

You can change the display by giving `subparsers` a `metavar` value, e.g.

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(...., metavar='{a,b,c,d}')
```

---

http://bugs.python.org/issue9026

is the bug fix that set it to OrderedDict.  In was closed in March 2011.

Comment: Yes, print type(subparser.choices) returns dict not OrderedDict, so that's the problem. Adding the metavar allows me to add whatever text I want there, which is nice. Should I file a bug report on this?

Comment: I found the bug report from 2011.  What is your Python version.

Comment: I had the python version mentioned in the question, but somebody edited the question and deleted that information. I rolled it back (by the way, it's python 2.7.7)

Comment: If I'm reading the bug issue correctly, this change appeared in 2.7.2

Comment: Is it possible that you are loading an older, local, copy of `argparse.py`?  For example if you downloaded an `argparse.py` for use with 2.6 some years ago.  `argparse.__file__` might tell you the source.